# How to deal with a broken link?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/89/40999) has two broken links. The answer itself will be fine since it already recite the summary of the link content, but what should be done with the link?

**Leave it alone? Comment that they are broken? Remove the hyperlink?**

Comment: Note: the linked answer only contains one link (which was broken). Are you talking about a broken link in another answer as well?

Comment: @V2Blast The broken wheel content is broken, but the page itself loads

Comment: That is indeed mentioned in a different answer :P However, the Burning Wheel link just pointed to a "main page" of what I assume was the old website in wiki format. I fixed that link as well as a broken link redirecting to a malicious website in yet another answer.

Comment: @V2Blast Just as a note, the old wiki and the current main site *aren’t* equivalent, but in that specific case the answer was treating them as the same, so that edit happens to work for it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Ah, I figured as much; it's just that the answer linked to the "main page" of the wiki rather than any particular wiki article so I figured there wasn't much point in finding an archived version or the new destination of the page.

Comment: @V2Blast Yep, the writer was just using it as “this is Burning Wheel”.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few options:

- Find a working current version of the linked page
- Find an archived version of the originally linked page (e.g. on the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/))
- If you can't fix the link yourself, or if you don't have time, leave a comment to let the answerer and others know so that someone else can fix it

In this particular case, I've found an archived version of the linked page and edited the answer to use it.